# People downvote the question if we downvote their answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have noticed that. If we downvote some of the people's answers, then they will downvote our question.

What's the reason & how to come out from this situation?

I know that in Stack Overflow there is no possibility to check who has cast a downvote or upvote.

Comment: I've noticed that questions with a disputable premiss get downvoted all on their own.

Comment: So you know you cant check who downvoted, yet you're making assumption you know who it is?

Comment: Yes making assumption

Comment: Incorrect Assumptions more then likely

Answer (score 4):

The downvotes may well be from other people viewing the question. You can never be sure, unless somebody posts a comment indicating that he/she downvoted the question. Likewise, the answerers cannot be sure that *you* downvoted their answer.

> What's the reason & how to come out from this situation?

The same as with other downvotes; write good, concise questions which are on-topic on the site you're at.

Comment: You can never be sure who has downvoted you *even if they do comment*.

Comment: @Servy yes, I'm talking about comments like '-1, not enough research'. That's still not *juridical* evidence, but ...

Comment: Like I said, even then, you cannot be sure.  You might be fairly confident, but you can *never* be *sure* until you get hired by SE and get a look at their database.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the reason?

Because people are, well, human. With emotions, that sometimes overrides common sense.

> How to come out from this situation?

To prevent it from happening in the first place, just think twice before commenting on bad answer after you downvote it. Of course it's good and desireable to comment, but if your reputation isn't really high, and you're afraid downvote will be meaningful and hurting, just don't comment. Or at least try to be gentle when doing so, e.g. don't throw "-1, answer is wrong" but rather explain why it's wrong in a gentle way.

After it already happened, there's not much you can do, as others here already said. Since you can't be sure the one you downvoted really downvoted you, commenting on their answer about it won't be a good idea. The only way I can see, assuming you both have enough reputation, is starting a new chat room with that user, and in there start with something like "Do you want to discuss your answer?", which might lead to friendly outcome, and possibly removal of the revenge vote, if that was really the case.

Answer (score 2):

You state you know that you cannot know who voted on you and still you are pretty sure who downvoted you. That doesn't make sense right?

The phenomena you describe is real though. Some users are there to get quick reputation. If you downvote them, and make that explicit by the comment you give, they will downvote your question.

There is actually not much to do about this type of user. Just accept the vote and hope the community will correct the voting, which will often be the case if the question is good.